# Delphi asynchronous write to TListBox from TCPServer OnExecute, TThread and TTimer

Tags: multithreading, delphi, tlistbox

I have an application where I'd like to add data to a TListBox called `listMessages` and I want to that from a `TTimer`, a TCPServer's `OnExecute` event and from several `TThreads` created from myself  :

```
procedure TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  listMessages.Items.Add('some data');
end;

procedure myTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  listMessages.Items.Add('some data');
end;

procedure TThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  listMessages.Items.Add('some data');
end;
```

So my question is - how can I achieve this thread safe ?